# After 13.10 Upgrade: ROXTerm default terminal

Tags: 13.10, gnome-terminal

I have just upgraded to 13.10 and found that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> will now launch ROXTerm (of which I haven't even heard before). Opening a "Terminal" from the Dash still opens the old gnome terminal.

Why did this change with the upgrade and how can I (or shouldn't I?) set gnome terminal to be the default again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

I could bring up a menu to choose the gnome-terminal once again. Seems to work fine so far. ROXTerm seems to have more options, but not knowing how it got to be my default terminal made me want to switch back.